# Telnet at Login Question

Tags: login, scripts

I am trying to setup a dummy terminal.   The system automatically signs in as the user I want.   The next step is for it to automatically telnet to a server.

I have the autologin working and the system is going to the prompt.

I have edited the .bash_profile to have the line "telnet 10.0.0.1"
The problem is the telnet is failing.

I get the following at start up
   "unable to connect to the remote host: Network is unreachable."
    username@hostname:~$

I can type at the prompt telnet 10.0.0.1 and it works fine.

Any ideas on how to get this to automatically telnet at startup?

I did as you suggested. I did make sure the network was set to the default connection.

The system boots up and is still just going to the prompt and not running a telnet net session.

Comment: Could you provide information about Ubuntu version, desktop, terminal you want use? As I understood, you want to get ready terminal window with telnet logged when you login to your desktop, right?

Answer (score 0):

We need to know a bit more about your situation.  Specifically, which version of Ubuntu?  Is your network connection Wireless or Wired? Do you have DHCP or a static address? Certain versions of Ubuntu around the 2008-2009 timeframe could not handle static addresses within the GUI Network configuration tool.

I'll take a stab at it, though. I'll assume you are using the Desktop and not Server variant, with the appropriate GUI config tools.

1) Log into your GUI account, at the dash type Network.  Click on the icon that looks like a folder with an Ethernet jack in it.

2) Click on the default connection, click on options button.  On the new page click the General tab, and make sure both those two top boxes are checked.  Then logout and verify from VT1 that the redirection happens for that user.

Comment: I am using 12.04 desktop.  I am using DHCP.

Comment: Thanks for that - please update your original question.  Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I did as you suggested. I did make sure the network was set to the default connection.

The system boots up and is still just going to the prompt and not running a telnet net session.

Comment: @user249246 Let me refer you to the Gentoo Handbook, specifically networking: http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=4&chap=1 . You may need to apt-get install dhclient or dhcpcd and tell NetworkManager to take a hike.